# Hard code window.document.referrer

Tags: javascript, jquery, referrer

I have a form that needs to pull a value from the referrer URL and set it as the value of an input field. I need to be able to test this locally before pushing a change, but not sure how to set the header in chrome/firefox to hard code the URL.

I'm using the following to grab the referrer, apply a regex to grab what I need, and set the result into a text with id `imageid`:

```
var regexp = /assets\/(\d+)/;
        var encodeID = regexp.exec(window.document.referrer);
        if (encodeID !== null && encodeID.length == 1){
           $("#imageid").val(encodeID[1]);
        }else{
          $("#imageid").val();
        }
```

Comment: and what will you do when browsers have their `donottrack` checkbox ticked? Because *lots* of them do, and even if they don't, https requests no longer add in the referrer, because that would reveal information that reveals data that can be exploited for security purposes.

Comment: That's not an issue, as the people using this specific page will not be using that option. The referrer page passes a URL with a numeric value at the end, which is stripped off and set into a textbox to speed up the users process.

Comment: if you want to hard code it anyway, why not just use a string instead of `window.document.referrer` ?

Comment: I think the issue was that I was trying to pull the referrer url within a click function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy solution was to just run the app and on the page pulling the referrer, apply this logic to the page in console:

```
var regexp = /assets\/(\d+)/;
var encodeID = regexp.exec(window.document.referrer);
if (encodeID !== null && encodeID.length == 1){
   $("#imageid").val(encodeID[1]);
}else{
    var regexp = /assets\/(\d+)/;
    var encodeID = regexp.exec(window.document.referrer);
   $("#imageid").val(encodeID[1]);
}
```